# Jar size of Guava dependency - is there a small version?

Tags: java, collections, jar, dependencies, guava

I just recently upped the version of Guava library from 9 to 10 and noticed quite an increase in the jar file size. 1.5MB just to have some lib to filter collections... (that's really what I ever use it for - but I might want to use more of what it has to offer)

Is there a distribution of Guava that offers just the basics and is not huge? I was looking for something in the range of 50-250 KB not 1.5MB. (or really anything smaller, like 500k would still be okay)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The official position on this is:

> We considered this very carefully when we started Guava, and we believe that a single JAR, with a recommendation of ProGuard to size-sensitive applications, is the way to go.

(taken from [their issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=605))

So, no, any version that splits the library into several smaller JARs will not be the official one, and you probably have to compile/prepare it yourself.

Comment: This is the only way, because it's absolutely inevitable that *any* slice we tried to make of Guava _for_ you would have only some of the stuff you want and tons of the stuff you don't. ProGuard has made it easy for you to slice it yourself.